# How do I print a dictionary on a single line in jinja2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jinja2

I have the variable `fruits`:

```
fruits = {
  "apple": {},
  "banana": {
    "params": {
      "color": "yellow",
      "size" 100
    }
  }
}
```

..and a jinja2 template `my_stuff.j2`:

```
In my bag I have:
{% for k,v in fruits.iteritems() %}
- {{ k }}
{% endfor %}
```

When I render it I get:

```
In my bag I have:
- apple
- banana
```

**Question**: How do I reach this:

```
In my bag I have:
- apple
- banana color="yellow" size="100"
```

Comment: Build another for loop that loops over `v.iteritems()` and format it the way you wanted?  Also suffix/prefix the control statements with `-` to stop white spaces from being rendered before/after them, i.e. `{{- ... -}}` and `{%- ... -%}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you can do it like this:

```
for key,val in fruits.iteritems():
    if val.get('params'):
        print key + ' ' + str(' '.join('{}={}'.format(param_key, param_val) for param_key, param_val in val['params'].items()))
    else:
        print key
```

And in `Jinja` you can do something like this:

```
{%for key,val in something.iteritems()%}
    {%if val.get('params')%}
        - {{key}} {%for item in val['params'].items()%} {{item | join ('=') }} {%endfor%}
    {%else%}
        - {{key}}
    {%endif%}
{%endfor%}
```